# What are the possibilities of getting NULL IBOutlets while loading a view.. IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have been working on IOS application. Before I had single project in which all source code was there application loaded properly in that setup, now I had split that into multiple projects. After that I am facing now a problem... in ViewDidLoad, IBOutlet for buttons all are coming nil values, view also loading black colored. I am not able to guess what was the problem. Any idea about what could cause this...

I have loaded my view like this...

```
 main =[[main_page_controller alloc] init];

    if (main != NULL) 
        [root.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
```

I am not sure which part of the code do I need to post here, to make the question more understandable... Please share your suggestions..

Edit:  I ran my old project and then tried with my new set up application launching successfully. I removed the application from device, and loaded using new set up only, problem again shows up. So what was there in old set up? What am I missing in new... ????

Comment: Ya, I have tried that before, still no luck :(

Comment: also use initWithNibNamed instead if init. Also check the view outlet is connected to view or not

Comment: When I split the project, I just copied files and made separate folders, will it cause the connection to break?

Comment: Not sure, sometimes the reference may change

Comment: @MidhunMP "in the viewDidLoad the IBOutlets will be nil sometimes, because your view is being loaded not completed." Do you have a source for this? `viewDidLoad` is called after `loadView`, which for .xibs, sets up all the `IBOutlet`s. I think that statement is false

Comment: @WDUK: there are a lot of scenarios in which the loadView is not called.

Comment: @MidhunMP It will **always** be called when you try to access `.view` on the View Controller for the first time (which you'll have to when displaying the view!). From the docs: "The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property."

Comment: @MidhunMP This is how `loadView` works. If the property is nil, and you try to access `.view.` via **the getter**, then `loadView` will be called. After that has finished, `viewDidLoad` will then be called. If you set the value of `.view` explicitly, the **getter** is not called, and `loadView` consequently isn't called either. Simple as. It doesn't help the case that the statements that brought this discussion to light (and others since) have since been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a)

> To initialize your view controller object using a nib, you use the initWithNibName:bundle: method to specify the nib file used by the view controller. Then, when the view controller needs to load its views, it automatically creates and configures the views using the information stored in the nib file.

When initialising a view controller, and you're using a .xib file for the view, you need to call `initWithNibName:bundle:`. This means it'll use the xib file to create the view within `loadView`. At the moment, you're just using `init`, that will create a blank `UIViewController` object.

So in this case, your code would be (assuming the .xib is called "MainViewControllerView.xib" within the main bundle):

```
main =[[main_page_controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewControllerView" bundle:nil];
if (main) {
    [root.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
}
```

Also sanity check your .xib file to see if all the `IBOutlet`s are connected to what you want.

Comment: While trying with nib name it crashes, Could not load nib... Any idea?

Comment: Do you have the correct nib name? Is the nib part of the correct target? Is it a part of the bundle.

Comment: nib names seems correct. Ya it is part of bundle. But what u mean by correct target here? I have a workspace, two projects are added, one project is loading the nib of other project. Will it work?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html . To change the target, have the right hand side inspector open, select the nib on the left, and make sure the correct target is checked on the right.

Comment: Can you please tell me ... what and all changes do we need to make to load a nib which is in another project(same workspace)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. You can have sub-projects (See http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/), which might do the trick. Otherwise, you may simply have to copy over the .xib file to your other project. Wish I could be more help in this regard, it's an area I'm not too familiar with, and is a significant tangent from the original answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21009/discussion-between-newbee-and-wduk)

Comment: I have fixed the problem, Issue was all my xib's need to include in main project, but I was put xib in their corresponding projects, now I  moved all xibs to main project, now everything fine.

Answer (score 1):

First check all your connection in xib(nib) file, if its already connected then just disconnect them , clean project **(cmd+k)** and then connect connection again.

take a look on this image for connection

[image]